# Visual Basic Input Error Messages

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, syntax-error, basic

I'm currently working on a project and I need some example VB input error messages.

It has been a long time since I have dealt with VB and I was wondering if anyone would mind sending some screenshots of input error messages? Such as and arithmatic overflow error message.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
On Error Resume Next
For x = 0 to 2000
    err.raise x
    If not err.description = "Unknown runtime error" then
        wscript.echo err.number & " " & err.description
    End If
    err.clear
Next
```

Help has a full list of runtime and syntax errors. Above vbs prints out all runtime errors.